# C# How do you change macOS mouse tracking speed?

Tags: c#, macos, mouse

I want to make a sensitivity slider on my RTS game. But I have no clue how to access the mouse tracking speed on Mac nor how to change it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking "How can my C# program change a user's mouse tracking speed when run on MacOS?"

Comment: Yeah. How to make a C# program to change a user's mouse tracking speed when run on MacOS? Wasnt so clear.

Comment: I don't have a clue how to do this.  However, unless you are writing a utility (intended to change the mouse tracking speed), don't you think this is a bad idea?  Someone runs your program and suddenly the behavior of _their_ computer changes.

Comment: Defenetly but there isnt any other practical way to do it i think. That's how WC3 doest it, how mobas do it. Its either changing the computer's settings directly or a laggy mouse.

Answer (score 0):

[Mouse acceleration commands](https://osxdaily.com/2010/08/25/mouse-acceleration/)

One way to change the speed is if you could access the command line with C# and execute

```
defaults read -g com.apple.mouse.scaling (VALUE)
```

When (VALUE) is omitted, it shows the current mouse speed.

If there is a macOS terminal/cmd executable, you could try to run the speed change with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` as used in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands).